# Exception while executing: Type mismatch for 'Value Selector' operator

Tags: mule

I am getting the below exception while triggering the mule template.

As I understand it, Mule is expecting the output in certain format and it's not getting that. My input payload is the technical metadata (pulling schema, table column names) from PostgreSQL database.

> ```
> Exception while executing: 
>   name: payload01.schema_name.table_name,
>         ^
> Type mismatch for 'Value Selector' operator
>      found :string, :name
>   required :datetime, :name or
>   required :localdatetime, :name or
>   required :object, :name or
>   required :time, :name or
>   required :array, :name or
>   required :date, :name or
>   required :localtime, :name or
>   required :period, :name.
> ```

Below is the configuration XML. I am not sure of what mime type I need to use for input Fields from database and where I need to make the changes. I gave it as JSON and it doesn't help.

```
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">




    <dw:input-payload  mimeType="json"/>




        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
```

%output application/java

payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {

```
externalId: payload01.schema_name,




name: payload01.schema_name
```

})]]>

```
    </dw:transform-message>




            <collibra-dgc:upsert-assets config-ref="CollibraDGC__Connection_Managament_type_strategy" assetTypeId="00000000-0000-0000-0001-000400000002" defaultDomainId="#[flowVars.'dom-id']" externalSystemId="GP" doc:name="CollibraDGC">




        <collibra-dgc:assets ref="#[payload]"/>




    </collibra-dgc:upsert-assets>




</sub-flow>




 <sub-flow name="postgreSub_Flow">




    <enricher source="#[payload.id]" target="#[flowVars['table-type-id']]" doc:name="Message Enricher">




        <collibra-dgc:get-asset-type-by-name config-ref="CollibraDGC__Connection_Managament_type_strategy" assetTypeName="Table" doc:name="CollibraDGC"/>




    </enricher>




    <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration1" doc:name="Database">





    Does anybody know how to solve this?
```

Comment: your config XML is incomplete

Comment: Hi JoostD, thanks. I have added the configuration xml. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: schema_name is fetched as a string not as a object from the database.Check how the response is returned from database